# Single quote query issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am facing an issue of single quote input in sql query. Query is below.

```
Dim query As String = "insert into users(comment) values ('" & txt_comment.Text & "')"
```

It is working fine. However When user inputs a single code data in textbox then query gets crash. Input example like " henry's ". Anyone would like to suggest me what should I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use parameterized queries. This also prevents SQL Injection issues

Comment: SQL is expecting all the quotes to be closed, what is not happening in your example.Just make sure that all your queries are built exactly as expected independently upon the user inputs. BTW, this specific code is very SQL-injection friendly: you should always check the query before connecting to the server (parameterised queries, as suggested by Matt, would take care of this automatically).

Comment: Did someone say "Little Bobby Tables" ?

Answer (score 6):

**[USE PARAMETERISED QUERIES!!](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)**

Sorry to shout, but I cannot stress how important this is. The example you have given of `"Henry's"` is actually a tame example, and will just cause the query to fail. Someone could input  `"Henry'; DROP TABLE users;--"`, and now you have lost your users table.

Even if you have restricted input, such as a drop down list, you should still use parameterised queries since they allow for much stronger typing, and also allow query plans to be used from the cache.

I have not used VB.NET in years, so forgive any syntax errors, but I think you want something like:

```
Dim query As String = "insert into users(comment) values (@Comment);"

Using connection As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
    Using command As New SqlCommand(query, connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = txt_comment.Text
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score -4):

You need to duplicate the quotes:

```
Dim query As String = "insert into users(comment) values ('" & txt_comment.Text.replace("'","''") & "')"
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution, open to sql injection security issues.

Comment: I totally agree that parametrized queries are better.